# 2 counts of InaccessibleWSDLException

Tags: java, wsdl

estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que consome um web service de uma empresa terceira.

Quando rodo a aplicação via Eclipse ela funciona perfeitamente.

Porém quando rodo via linha de comando, o erro "2 counts of InaccessibleWSDLException" é apresentado sempre que chamo qualquer um dos seus serviços.

Linha de Comando: java -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -jar  C:\omni\clientes\fac\java\IcaptorECob.jar

O que devo fazer? Qual a diferença entre executar pelo Eclipse e fora dele?

Comment: Por favor poste a stacktrace completa do erro

Comment: Marquezani, desculpe pela demora. Está difícil de pegar a stacktrace do erro pois estou rodando pela linha de comando. Mas o erro foi o seguinte: Unexpected Error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty.

Comment: Este erro é quando o sistema não acha o certificado (arquivo.JKS). Porém o certificado está na pasta indicada.

Answer (score 0):

Crie a pasta **classes** dentro da pasta WEB-INF, depois crie a pasta **META-INF** dentro da pasta **classes**.

A estrutura ficará assim: `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF`.

Coloque o arquivo `jax-ws-catalog.xml` na pasta **META-INF** recém criada.

Coloque o arquivo `nomedoarquivo.wsdl` na pasta **META-INF** recém criada.

O arquivo `jax-ws-catalog.xml` deve conter a seguinte informação:

```
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog" prefer="system">
<system systemId="http://localhost/wsdl/nomedoarquivo.wsdl" uri="nomedoarquivo.wsdl"/></catalog>
```

Agora é só referenciar o wsdl para o endereço http://localhost/wsdl/nomedoarquivo.wsdl na sua classe de Serviço.

Quando o sistema procurar o wsdl no endereço http://localhost/wsdl/nomedoarquivo.wsdl, ele será redirecionado para o arquivo local.

Comment: Obrigado. Vou neste fim de semana fazer os testes. Posto o resultado em seguida.